# Defining multiple cases - which case these will get?

Tags: flutter, dart

In the following piece will the `ConnectionState.none` and `ConnectionState.waiting` give the `CircularProgressIndicator`? Is it legal to define cases that way?

```
switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
    case ConnectionState.none:
    case ConnectionState.waiting:
    case ConnectionState.active:
        return const CircularProgressIndicator();
    case ConnectionState.done:
        ...
```

Comment: yes, and even if it wasn't legal, police won't come to catch you xD

Comment: Make sure to end each case with `break` so the other cases don't run.

Comment: @OMiShah That isn't legal in Dart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use multiple cases too. But instead of multiple cases, we can use or operator in a single **switch** case itself.

```
switch (connection) {
        case connection.none:
        case connection.waiting:
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
        }
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this `case x | y:` in dart